# What Has Happened To BIDS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have Visual Studio Pro 2015 installed, SQL Server 2012 Management Studio but if I run `Select @@Version` I get SQL Server 2008 R2 - now my ? is....how can I get BIDS so that I can create SSIS packages?

Comment: From [Wikipedia: Business Intelligence Development Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Development_Studio): "BIDS is not supported with Visual Studio 2010 and later, and has been replaced by SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to download **SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)** separately from this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

This release supports SQL Server 2016 through SQL Server 2005

[image: Supported SQL versions]